Does this metal plate stay on my prehung door frame after installation?
I bought an exterior prehung door to install for my garage. Does this metal plate stay on? Or do I take it off?


It's a reinforcement plate, to prevent a casual kick from splintering the door jamb and popping open the door.
It goes between the inner jamb and the underlying framing. The four staples hold it in place while you pre-drill screw holes through the jamb and into the frame. You can leave it in place to correctly position the holes.

If you can get the frame into the wall opening without removing it, I'd leave it.
Normally there is some space between the frame and the wall opening sides, where shims can be used to align the frame level and plumb, even if the opening is out of plumb a bit. The metal piece looks like it could fall within these usual shim gaps.
The metal also looks like it could provide a bit of extra strength to the strike hole.
